# How to convert Image URL (image stored in GCS) to binary for uploading image to facebook graph API

Tags: go, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, whatsapp

I'm trying to update the WhatsApp profile picture using facebook graph API in Go. As the graph API only accepts the image file as binary, and my image file is already uploaded in google bucket, I need to convert the file to binary.

When I try to read file from GCS by creating MediaURL and below code returns error. It says "no such file or directory". The url is opened in the browser.

`bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(gcsUrl)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an error because it tries to resolve the path on your local, not remote path

first, you need to pull the image

```
resp, err := http.Get(gcsUrl)
   if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("GET error: %v", err)
    }
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

then you can read that data  `data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`

ReadAll takes `io.Reader` type data and `resp.Body` is compatible to that

Comment: how can I use it for uploading to Facebook (GraphAPI) ?  I'm referring this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload

Comment: You can use https://pkg.go.dev/net/http this package to call Facebook api's

Comment: I'm already using the package, as you can see facebook only accept file as binary. So with this how is this possible ?

Comment: You can ask new question related to that